# different IDs but same class name problem

Tags: php, jquery, attributes, hover

I have displayed a row of items with same div class name but different div IDs

I'm trying to use jquery to capture the different IDs when i hover over the items. But right now, each item I'm hovering over, I'm only getting the latest ID and not that specific ID I when I hover.

This is my php:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$id = $row['id'];
echo "<div class='row'><div class='a' id='a_".$id."'>do something</div></div>";
}
```

Assume, that this will have 10 rows, and each row of divs will have unique IDs

Then this is my jquery:

```
 $('.row').hover(function(){
    var a = $('.a').attr('id');
    alert(a);
    }, function(){

});
```

Can someone help me figure out why I'm only getting the latest ID (all being the same), and not different ID's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
var a = $('.a').attr('id');
```

to

```
var a = $('.a', this).attr('id');
```

The reason you're only getting the last ID with the former is that your query doesn't specify any context, meaning you're searching the entire document for `a` classes. When using the `attr()` method on a multi-element jQuery object, it will only return the attribute from the last one.

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/h7QDX/

Comment: I dont think that .find('.a').hover... would work in my case because <div class='a'> is a small div item which I'm trying show when I'm tryhing to hover over the entire row div. I tried this method, but it doesn't alert when I hover over the row div

Comment: @andrewliu Like I said, it was only an example of how you could optimise it *if* the hover event was only to be attached to the inner div. If that is not the case, ignore my second example

Comment: Oh yeah, okay but i tried your first example, but its giving me undefined? why does this happen? Thank you

Comment: @andrewliu Can you post the generated markup from your PHP loop (ie, what you see when you "view source" on the page)?

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure how I can post everything, but it seems everything is in righteous order. I have multiple divs (<div class='row'></div>). Then between that row divs, I have <div class='a' id='a_#'></div> which # is different numbers. However, I do have a style on that div, which is style='display:none;float:right;z-index:9999' Will that make a difference?

Comment: @andrewliu You can edit your original question to add more information. I only need to see the 10 lines generated from your loop. I've also added a JSFiddle demo to my answer.

Comment: Oh I'm an idiot. I forgot that . (dot) in front of a... Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = $('.a', this).attr('id');
```

You need to provide the context (`this`) if you want to find specific elements in the current context.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the rendered mark-up of your php script is similar to the following:

```
<div id="currentTarget"></div> <!-- just for the purposes of the demo -->
<div class='row'><div class='a' id='a_1'>do something</div></div>
<div class='row'><div class='a' id='a_2'>do something</div></div>
<div class='row'><div class='a' id='a_3'>do something</div></div>
<div class='row'><div class='a' id='a_4'>do something</div></div>
<div class='row'><div class='a' id='a_5'>do something</div></div>
<div class='row'><div class='a' id='a_6'>do something</div></div>
```

The following jQuery works to retrieve the `id` of the `.a` element using `hover()`:

```
$('.a').hover(
    function(){
        $('#currentTarget').text(this.id);
        // retrieve the id with: this.id
    },
    function(){
        $('#currentTarget').text('');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6YRVw/).

The above, obviously, relies on the `.a` element itself being hovered; if you want to trigger the same by hovering over the `.row` elements, then:

```
$('.row').hover(
    function(){
        $('#currentTarget').text($(this).find('.a').attr('id'));
        // retrieve the id with: $(this).find('.a').attr('id')
    },
    function(){
        $('#currentTarget').text('');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6YRVw/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Here: 
`var a = $('.a').attr('id');`
you get the first item with class 'a'
you want $(this)

like this:

```
$('.row').hover(function(){
    var a = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(a);
    }, function(){

});
```

if you want the div witch contains the '.row' use .parent (many times as div`s)

like this:

```
$('.row').hover(function(){
    var a = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    alert(a);
    }, function(){

});
```

Comment: He's after the inner div ID, not the outer `row` div

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$('.row').hover(function(){
    var a = $('.a').attr('id');
    alert($('.a',this).attr('id'));
    }, function(){

});
```